# Read-only application cannot POST with the twitter ruby gem

Tags: ruby, twitter

I have the following ruby script:

```
puts "Checkpoint 1"
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

Twitter.configure do |config|
    config.consumer_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    config.consumer_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    config.oauth_token = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    config.oauth_token_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
end
Twitter.verify_credentials
puts "Checkpoint 2"
Twitter.update("It is a Myth That Entrepreneurs Drive New Technology http://www.slate.com/articles/health_and_science/new_scientist/2013/09/entrepreneurs_or_the_state_innovation_comes_from_public_investment.html")
puts "Checkpoint 3"
```

It gets to Checkpoint 2 but not to checkpoint 3, and it gives the following error:

> Read-only application cannot POST

But that's not true, because when I go to dev.twitter.com and check the preferences for my app it says:

> Access level   Read, write, and direct messages

So no read-only stuff. I'm completely lost here, what might be the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell there are two possibly simple explanations to this. Possibly that you did not update your access token after you changed your app from read-only to Read/Write. Or, that your email address has not yet been verified.

Comment: Yiiiihaaa!! thanks! For the record, your first guess was right, I hadn't updated my access token after changing the app from read-only to read/write.